# Навигационные свойства при миграции

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

Всем привет.
Добавляю с БД табличку. В Entity модели у нее есть ряд навигационных свойств.
Вопрос. Как сделать так, чтобы при миграции в БД не создавались столбцы по этим навигационным свойствам?

Пример модели:

```
public class TransferFormEntity : GuidBasedEntity
{
    public Guid CallTransferId { get; set; }
    public string TranserFormIdentifier { get; set; }
    public string? OperatorSignature { get; set; }
    public string? Stamp { get; set; }
    public byte IsOutbound { get; set; }

    #region Navigation

    public virtual UserCallEventEntity? UserCallEvent { get; set; }
    public virtual CallerEntity? Caller { get; set; }
    public virtual GlobalDataEntity? Global { get; set; }
    public virtual UserEntity? User { get; set; }
    public virtual CallerRequestEntity? CallerRequest { get; set; }
    public virtual CallTransferDataEntity? CallTransfer { get; set; }
    #endregion
}
```

Миграция создает вот такую таблицу:

```
migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
            name: "TransferForm",
            schema: "dbo",
            columns: table => new
            {
                ID = table.Column<Guid>(type: "uuid", nullable: false),
                CallTransferId = table.Column<Guid>(type: "uuid", nullable: false),
                TranserFormIdentifier = table.Column<string>(type: "text", nullable: false),
                OperatorSignature = table.Column<string>(type: "text", nullable: true),
                Stamp = table.Column<string>(type: "text", nullable: true),
                IsOutbound = table.Column<byte>(type: "smallint", maxLength: 4, nullable: false),
                UserCallEventId = table.Column<int>(type: "integer", nullable: true),
                CallerId = table.Column<Guid>(type: "uuid", nullable: true),
                GlobalId = table.Column<int>(type: "integer", nullable: true),
                UserId = table.Column<Guid>(type: "uuid", nullable: true),
                CallerRequestCallerId = table.Column<Guid>(type: "uuid", nullable: true),
                CallerRequestUserCallEventId = table.Column<int>(type: "integer", nullable: true)
            },
```

Пока на ум пришло только попробовать удалить из миграции сгерерированные в коде выше не нужные столбцы и обновить БД. Но правильно ли это ?

Comment: Повесить `[NotMapped]` на игнорируемые свойства?

Comment: Если их убрать, то не будет работать навигация.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov я просто смотрю другие миграции моделей, где тоже есть навигационные свойства. И там в файле миграции нет этих столбцов

Comment: @EvgeniyZ спасибо, попробую

Comment: Повторю ещё раз: при удалении столбцов перестанут работать навигации. Свойства станут бессмысленны. / В других моделях точно такие же навигационные свойства? Или там коллекции? Или чем-то ещё отличаются?